# Can I break up the 3D line integral $\int_{K,p} (2xydx + (x^3 + 3z)dy + 3ydz)$ in three single integrals?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, 3d, line-integrals

$$\int_{γ,p} (2x \ y \ dx + (x^3 + 3z) \ dy + 3y \ dz)$$ where $$γ = [(0, 0, 0),(0, 1, 3)] ∪ \{
(x, y, z) ∈ \mathbb{R^3}|y = 0, \ x^2 + (z − 3)^2 = 9,  \ x ≤ 0\} ∪ [(0, 0, 6),(1, 1, 6)]$$
and p is the orientation so that $(0,1,3)$ is the first end.

---

It looks to me as if each term is meant to be integrated over the range of only one variable: am I wrong? E.g., $$\int_{γ,p} 2x \ y \ dx + \int_{γ,p} (x^3 + 3z) \ dy  + \int_{γ,p} 3y \ dz $$ and the first integral becoming, for instance, $$\int_{γ_!,p} 2x  \ y  \ dx + \int_{γ_2,p} 2x \ y \ dx  + \int_{γ_3,p} 2x \ y \ dx  = \int_0^0 0 \ ydx + \int_0^3 2x \ 0 \ dx  + \int_0^1 2x \ x \ dx = x^2|_0^1 = 1 $$

Am I off? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the scalar product and the linearity of the line integral give for some vector function $A$:
$$
\int\limits_C A \cdot du = 
\int\limits_C \left(\sum_i A_i \, e_i \right) \cdot du =
\sum_i  \int\limits_C A_i \, e_i \cdot du = 
\sum_i  \int\limits_C A_i \, dx_i    
$$
where the $e_i$ are the canonical base vectors.

Comment: Clear as day. Sorry I can't upvote yet!